# How do I remotely access a virtual Ubuntu Machine?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

What is the easiest (no configuration on router, firewall, etc) way to access Ubuntu (virtual machine inside a Ubuntu real machine) from outside my network?

***Long version:***

I don't really know how my home network works (2 or 3 routers, 6 computers, my father control the network).

But what I need is to be able to see (and use (click,write)) on the Virtual Machine (running Ubuntu) inside my own machine (running Ubuntu).
    I'd rather not mess with the network (weird equilibrium). I think it's possible, but I don't know what works best and is the easiest to implement.

**Ps.**: Using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). I thought that there was a new program (new to Ubuntu, ported from Windows) that would go over all the port forwarding stuff (Am I wrong? )

**Ps2.**: Would it be easier to access my first machine (the host for the virtual machine) from outside? I so, I don't mind doing this from Ubuntu (not messing with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/es/download/index.aspx) is a remote access tool with zero configuration and it supports linux. I've found this tool to be the easiest way to control desktops from outside my network.

Comment: That's the one thanx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are using for the virtual machine.

Can you ssh to that physical machine?
Are you using virtual box?

If so look at this:
http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=148

Your VM software needs to forward a port to your physical machine.
Then you can either ssh to your physical machine and then to your VM or you can, if setup correctly, directly connect to your VM from the outside(as long as the router is forwarding you some ports to use for ssh).

Comment: Also if you are using Virtual Box 4(newest) see the documentation here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say hands down the easiest way is to set up port forwarding. I know a number of very talented CS grads that find this prohibitively difficult, and I'm not sure why. Just go to the port forwarding page in your router, and figure it out from there. It's just a few key strokes. Then use SSH with X forwarding.

You did say that you didn't want to change your network, so if there's a really great reason for this other than learning curve, ignore this post. In general, I would look to the built in linux tools before relying on a third party gui tool.